# Calling a starbasic function within starbasic kicks a ERROR

Tags: vba, libreoffice-calc

I am trying to use a VLOOKUP function within VBA on Libreoffice Calc.
The code I found here [enter link description here](https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/en-US/text/sbasic/shared/calc_functions.html)

```
Function MyVlook(Lookup, DataArray As Object, Index As Integer, SortedRangeLookup as Byte)
    Dim oService As Object
    Set oService = createUnoService("com.sun.star.sheet.FunctionAccess")
    ' Always use the function name in English
    MyVlook = oService.callFunction("VLOOKUP", Array(Lookup, DataArray, Index, SortedRangeLookup))
End Function
```

works fine if you call it from a cell.

```
=MYVLOOK(A7,$Sheet2.A:G,6,)
```

But when I try to call the function in another function I seem unable to get it to work

```
Function DEMO(lookup)
   DataArray = "$Sheet2.A:G"
   DEMO = MyVlook(lookup,DataArray,6,)
END Function
```

**Object Variable not set**

How to fix this?

#############UPDATE

After @JohnSUN correctled my function I ended up with this

```
Function MyVlook(Lookup, Index As Integer, SortedRangeLookup as Byte)
    Dim DataArray as object
    DataArray = ThisComponent.getSheets().getCellRangesByName("$Sheet2.A1:G10000")(0)

    Dim oService As Object
    Set oService = createUnoService("com.sun.star.sheet.FunctionAccess")
    ' Always use the function name in English
    MyVlook = oService.callFunction("VLOOKUP", Array(Lookup, DataArray, Index, SortedRangeLookup))
End Function
```

Although the function works it often kicks a error

```
BASIC runtime error.
An exception occured
Type: com.sun.star.lang.illegalArgumentException
Message:.
```

The script asking for the function is

```
Function CalcNight(icaoDep, icaoArr As String,t1,t2 As Date)

'Try and find the coordinates in sheet 2
lat1 = MyVlook(icaoDep,6,"false")

'If the AIRPORT can not be found
If IsEmpty(lat1) Then
    CalcNight = icaoDep & " Airport coordinates unknown"
    Exit Function
End If
lon1 = MyVlook(icaoDep,7,"false")

lat2 = MyVlook(icaoArr,6,"false")

'If the AIRPORT can not be found
If IsEmpty(lat2) Then
    CalcNight = icaoArr & " Airport coordinates unknown"
    Exit Function
End If
lon2 = MyVlook(icaoArr,7,"false")

'Rest of script that continues calculations with LAT/LON

End Function
```

Comment: This is not VBA — it's LibreOffice (Star)Basic. Edit the title, tags, and question to fix this problem. Also, what is `lookup`? Please provide a fully reproducible example.

Comment: ...and don't use STRING "$Sheet2.A:G". Do you see? in MyVlook DataArray is Object! So, `DataArray = ThisComponent.getSheets().getCellRangesByName("$Sheet2.A1:G10000")(0)`

Comment: @JohnSUN: Thank you for the answer as always. Still, I was hoping to wait for the OP to fix the question first, as this site values high-quality questions in case others come across them.

Comment: @JohnSUN Thank you for this solution. Sorry for being too new at this.